# How do I get the IP of a user in Nuxt's asyncData method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation, nuxt.js

Nuxt uses asyncData to run code server-side and then merges it with the data object.

I want to make a call that requires me to know the user's IP. [I see that I can get to the `req` object](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/) which does have it but it's buried [deep, deep](https://pastebin.com/w8aYbbJD) in there and I worry this is not a reliable way of doing it.

How can I access the calling user's IP address server-side instead of client-side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If nuxt is running behind a proxy such as nginx, then you can get the client's IP address in asyncData by reading x-real-ip or x-forwarded-for. Be aware that x-forwarded-for can contain comma separated IPs if a call has passed through additional proxys (if there is multiple entries, then the client is the first one).

Make sure to set up the headers in your nginx site configuration

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then you can read the headers in asyncData:

```
  async asyncData(context) {
    if (process.server) {
      const req = context.req
      const headers = (req && req.headers) ? Object.assign({}, req.headers) : {}
      const xForwardedFor = headers['x-forwarded-for']      
      const xRealIp = headers['x-real-ip']
      console.log(xForwardedFor)
      console.log(xRealIp)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great answer, I hadn't considered taking advantage of the server itself. What used to worry me about that - you'd get a series of IP addresses like you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

There was a github thread about this which makes grabbing the IP trivial in both environments (locally, production)

```
const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress
```

But be aware that you'll need to ensure the proxy headers are forwarded correctly. Because nuxt runs behind a traditional web server, without having the proxy headers forwarded, you'll always get the Local IP of the web server (127.0.0.1 unless loop back was changed).

Comment: I'm unable to figure this out as I'm hosting on Heroku and it seems that I get an array of `remoteAddress` and I really don't want to expose sensitive keys client side

Comment: This solution is brilliant client-side but doesn't seem to work in `asyncData` piece in Nuxt returning `undefined`