# How can I get client IP address in Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, ip-address

I want to know how to get client IP address in Nuxt.js.
I am using Nuxt.js in client side and Express in server side.
I thought I can get a client ip address in the server side by `req.connection.remoteAddress` or  `req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',').pop()` when server side receives an request.
However, by above codes, I can only get `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

I google and found that if I am using `nginx`, I can set `x-forwarded-for` by setting file, but I am not using `nginx`.
I may be using `@nuxtjs/proxy` (but I am not sure. I'm sorry but I do not understand proxy well.)

```
modules: [
 '@nuxtjs/axios',
 '@nuxtjs/pwa',
 '@nuxtjs/proxy',
 '@nuxtjs/auth',
],
proxy: {
 '/api/': {
   target: process.browser ? '' : 'http://localhost:3001',
   pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '/' },
 },
}
```

(A part of `nuxt.config.js`.)

By reading document of [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/) it seems that I can set `'x-forwarded-for'` header, but I do not know how to get client ip address its self, and I cannot set the header.

As an another way, I tried to set client ip address as a parameter, and used following codes.

`client side`

```
if (process.browser) {
  const ip = await this.$axios.$get('/ip/')
}
// send an request with this ip as a parameter.
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.browser ? '' : 'http://localhost:3001',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '/' },
    },
    '/ip/': {
      target: process.browser ? 'http://icanhazip.com' : 'http://icanhazip.com',
      pathRewrite: { '^/ip/': '/' },
    },
  },
```

But I can only get the same, server side, global ip address although I used `process.browser`.

Please help me to get client ip address in Nuxt.js.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335203/how-do-i-get-the-ip-of-a-user-in-nuxts-asyncdata-method

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I will check whether it works or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but the solution you taught me does not work.
All the ips I got are `undefined`.

In the solution, nginx is used and some settings are written to set headers.
But I just use `@nuxtjs/proxy` and I did not (know how to) write such settings.

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks for detailed feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Nuxt checkout the code described in this discusion -
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2914

Basically thel idea is to store the client IP in the request that the proxy recieves

```
export default ({ req, store }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    // https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2914
    const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress
    store.commit('SET_IP', ip)
  }
  if (process.client) {
    localStorage.setItem('ip', store.getters.ip)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer a lot.
I'm sorry but I am not using `nginx`.
I'm just using `@nuxtjs/proxy`.

Do you mean that by using `@nuxtjs/proxy` (or `Nuxt.js`), I am using `nginx`?
In that case, how can I find `proxy.conf`? I can only find `nuxt.config.js` in my nuxt project.

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks for detailed feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I can get ip address by your codes.
After that, by adding `app.$axios.defaults.headers.common.ip = store.getters.ip`, I could set ip address in the headers.