# Is there a way to block countries IPs for my Nuxt website?

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm using Nuxt.JS and host my Website on Vercel. I already tried things like this:

```
const response = await useFetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json');
const ipAddress = response.data._value.ip;
ipAddress.trim()
const details = await useFetch(`https://freeipapi.com/api/json/${ipAddress}`)
const countrycode = details.data._rawValue.countryCode

if(countrycode != 'CH' && countrycode != 'DE') {
  await navigateTo('/restricted')
}
```

However the the IP address is the one from Vercel, I think, but definitely not mine. Also, the country code isn't the one from me (as a user on my website)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335203/how-do-i-get-the-ip-of-a-user-in-nuxts-asyncdata-method

Comment: `However the the IP address is the one from Vercel, I think` this is correct, as the IP address you receive from the Ipify API will be that of the requester, ie. the hosting server. If you want to get the client's IP address, then you would need to make the request from the client-side instead.

Comment: If you're making this request from the server, then yeah, ipify will see the server's IP. Pass the IP of the requester along if you want information about the requester's IP. Ipify does not appear to have the option of passing any IP along, as its sole purpose is to give you _your_ IP. So look for a different IP-to-location API.

Comment: @Rory If you're doing this check on the client side, you may as well not do it at all, since it can be trivially bypassed there.

Comment: @deceze true - but then so can the entire premise of what the OP is trying to do :)

Comment: @Rory True. If you're really serious about geoblocking, you'll also need to block any known VPN IPs. That would finally raise the barrier high enough that most regular users won't circumvent it.

Comment: And that becomes a configuration arms race, as the VPN companies spin up new instances to combat geo-blocking. Long story short, either don't bother implementing this, or pay for a service who will manage it all for you.

Comment: Yes, blocking VPN services is a game you need to stay on top off, otherwise it's pointless…